# jQuery Animate Padding to Zero

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.4

I have the following snippet that toggles padding when hovering (see example [here](http://f.cl.ly/items/cfcdda6a1c0a1e0c5834/animation.html)):

```
<div id="outer"><div id="inner"></div></div> 
<script> 
  $("#inner").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#outer").animate({ 'padding' : '20px' }, "slow");
  });
  $("#inner").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#outer").animate({ 'padding' : '0px' }, "slow");
  });
</script>
```

The goal is to have the padding animate both in and out, however currently no animation appears for animating out. I did some tests, and if I change the leave padding to 10 pixels (from 0 pixels) it runs an animation, but starts at zero and animates outwards. I'm running jQuery 1.4.3. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but wouldn't animating a `margin` attribute for the inner element work instead ?

Comment: @Freek, not if the outer div has dimensions defined.. it would push the inners left/top, but it would break outside of the outer, as the outer cannot expand due to dimensions defined..

Comment: Seems this got reported. You can follow here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7399

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Definitely an animation bug in 1.4.3, for now you can work-around by animating the individual properties like this:

```
$("#inner").mouseleave(function () {
  $("#outer").animate({ 
    'padding-top' : 0,
    'padding-right' : 0,
    'padding-bottom' : 0,
    'padding-left' : 0,
  }, "slow");
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Sr5kZ/).

Comment: Thanks Nick! Always appreciate your very precise answers. Also, cool tool for code demos!

Comment: the bug exists in the sense that it does not store the padding after the animation somehow.. even if you remove the mouseleave completely, there is a problem when you re-enter the div. The animation starts over..

Comment: @Gaby -I think that's caused by the mouse position shifting into it, not sure why it's being removed at all though...I'm gonna get some sleep or coffee here one, then see where this is happening

Comment: yes but it should not reset the property on mouseenter.. asking for animation uses the current property values.. (*so it has not been stored or it gets reset. both wrong..*)

Comment: @Gaby - Yup, agreed, seems like the problem is definitely in the css re-write, values not being retrieved correctly explains all behavior, I'll narrow it down after getting ready for the day.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a bug in `1.4.3` (rewritten css part). `1.4.2` works fine:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/YjC6y/44/

I will investigate it further and update this post.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I appreciate the confirmation that it is a bug!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use a cssHook. [Brandon Aarons jquery-cssHooks](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/) come to mind (in this case the `padding` hook in `marginpadding.js`)

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/jitter/Kwawh/)

Answer (score 0):

I just realized jquery is not reacting very well to hyphens "-" within animation but you get the same result by getting ride of the hyphen and capitalizing the first letter after. So for you will have something like this:

```
    $("#inner").mouseleave(function () {
       $("#outer").animate({
     paddingTop : 0,
         paddingRight : 0,
         paddingBottom : 0,
         paddingLeft : 0,
         borderLeftWidth: 0,
         borderTopWidth: 0,
         borderRightWidth: 0,
         borderBottomWidth: 0,

 }, slow);
```