# -webkit-padding-start: 40px; What it should be for IE and Firefox?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

`-webkit-padding-start: 40px;` for Chrome

What it is for *IE* and *Firefox*?

Comment: Do you know Google? check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-padding-start)

Comment: @please try to respect people if you want people to respect you,as a user of stackoverflow and literate in english,i understand the terms of posting question,and i did try to search in google,maybe due to wrong keyword or such i failed of finding answers in both google and stackoverflow,thank you for your question and hope i answered you

Comment: @venkateshwar thanks, what about ie?microsoft is not as helpful

Comment: The link provides that information also. Cool :)

Comment: sorry,didnt saw that, :( .Hey,thnx a lot,means i cant do anything to IE?zzz

Comment: nope.. but there are many alternate ways to do that. using scripting languages like `jQuery` (because I am in jquery).

Comment: yeah,i see,so you can say jquery is easier than css for you :)  thanks a lot anyways

Comment: erm, hey any jquery you recommend? @venkateshwar

Comment: Till now I was searching the jquery thing. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095475/jquery-animate-padding-to-zero) may help you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Firefox, the property name is [`-moz-padding-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-padding-start). For IE, there is no counterpart (so far).

You can achieve the same effect using widely supported CSS features at least in a simple scenario where the page as a whole is either in left-to-right or in right-to-left layout and writing direction. Using `<html dir=ltr>` or `<html dir=rtl>`, respectively, you can write your CSS code like this:

```
[dir=ltr] .foo {
   padding-left: 2.5em;
}
[dir=rtl] .foo {
   padding-right: 2.5em;
}
```

This would correspond to `.foo { padding-start: 2.5em; }`. Of course, this approach means some duplication of code. But it works on almost 100% (including IE 7 and newer in Standad Mode).

Answer (score 10):

```
-moz-padding-start: 40px;
-webkit-padding-start: 40px;
-khtml-padding-start: 40px;
-o-padding-start: 40px;
padding-start: 40px;
padding: 40px;
```

I do not believe IE has a padding-start equivalent.