# odd formatting when appending elements with both jQuery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I don't understand why my `<li>` within my `<ol>` are displaying in this peculiar way. It is happening in both firefox and chrome. Somehow they are not aligning properly. This is happening when I create the elements with both jQuery and JavaScript.

```
var limit = 10000, wrapper = document.getElementById("vanilla_wrapper"), el;

for (var i = 0; i <= limit; i++){

    jq_wrapper.append("<li></li>");

}

for (var i = 0; i <= limit; i++){

    el = document.createElement("li");
    wrapper.appendChild(el);

}
```

[image: odd formatting with <li>]

**Edit**
[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/uLabiHiY/1/)

**Edit 2**

Adjusting the padding as suggested still has very odd formatting:

[image: After adjusted padding]
[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/uLabiHiY/7/edit)

Comment: Try adding `list-style-position: inside;` to your `ol` style.

Comment: Can you replicate in jsfiddle? I ran your code there and it seemed to format fine.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `ol` element has a `left-padding` automatically applied which create the space for the numbering..

It has a [default value of `40px`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ol.html#ol-display) so if your numbering text exceeds this, you get that problem..

You can increase it with

```
ol{
   padding-left: 60px;
}
```

Comment: I've adjusted the padding and the formatting is still odd. I made an edit and attached a screenshot. Can you take a look. Thank you.

Comment: @thomas, If you are talking about the top space and the fact that the red column has less items, then that happens as a protection of JSBIN.. it cuts off long loops that it considers might hang.. add `// noprotect` at the top (http://jsbin.com/uLabiHiY/14)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this

```
ol {margin: 0; list-style-position: inside; padding: 0;}
```

Comment: I've adjusted the padding and the formatting is still bizarre. can you take a look at the edit and attached screenshot and fiddle? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. Add your margin, then make sure it's vertically aligned to the top:

```
.jq { vertical-align: top }

ol li{
margin-left:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each browser dictates the formatting of the list marker, so you'll have to use browser specific properties to accomplish this. I'm looking into other browsers right now, but in the meantime, this is what I've found for Chrome (webkit):

```
td {
  padding: 0px; /*Or just remove it...*/
}
ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}
```

The default for `-webkit-padding-start` is 40px, which is what was throwing off your numbers above 1000. While others have suggested increasing the `padding` value, this will indent your numbers below 1000 too far and make them look odd. Using the `-padding-start` property will help keep the numbers in line. Stay tuned for more info on other browsers.

jsbin that works in chrome (I cut your `limit` down to 1500 just to reduce jsbin's lag): http://jsbin.com/uLabiHiY/18

**Edit:**

Here is the property for Firefox: `-moz-padding-start`

and Opera: `-o-padding-start`

It doesn't appear that IE has one (go figure...) but this link might provide a little insight on how to fix that: [-webkit-padding-start: 40px; What it should be for IE and Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549591/webkit-padding-start-40px-what-it-should-be-for-ie-and-firefox)