# Get rid of -webkit-padding-start: 40px

Tags: html, css, menu, webkit

I am working on adding a menu to a map. The menu is working fine except I noticed there is always a padding to the left no matter what CSS applied to the menu. The padding seems to be originated from (-webkit-padding-start: 40px;) and it does not want to go away. I tried to override it with `0 !important;` that didn't do anything.

After Googling found this:

[-webkit-padding-start: 40px; What it should be for IE and Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549591/webkit-padding-start-40px-what-it-should-be-for-ie-and-firefox)

However could not find anything else on how to override or make this go away. I need to have items in the menu all the way to the left.

[image]

Attached is a screenshot, green area is what I am talking about and under styles you can see -webkit-padding-start: 40px;

Comment: @sqe `margin-left: -40px;` this actually worked, I am still not sure where it is coming from?

Comment: See my answer below, it's because of the user-agent stylesheets of every browser.

Comment: After adding `margin-left: -40px;` this '-webkit-padding-start: 40px' still there but the menu is all the way to the left. Thank you.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It's because of the user-agent stylesheets of every browser.
You should always reset all attributes in your css as your first step.

**Short solution:**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* your styling */
```

**Longer solution:**

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: This also works. I would rather use `margin-left: -40px;` for now because that will only affect the menu not the whole project but in the next project will use css reset. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure to apply the `margin-left: -40px;` only on that specific menu (with applying an id like `#special-ul { margin-left: -40px; }`) in order to avoid the margin on **every** ul.

Comment: Thank you to both you and the thread creator, I was going nuts wondering where padding was appearing from no where!  Thanks guys.

Comment: You just applied a high-importance style to every element in the entire page. Readers: DO NOT DO THIS. If you want to apply margin and/or padding rules, do it in a way that is more specific than *.

Answer (score 2):

for firefox:

```
-moz-padding-start: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for a menu aswell and tried to correct it in the ul .navigation {} style I was using  but didn't work until I reset it in the ul {} itself - incase anyone else has the same trouble.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).