# CSS <ul> is taking an extra space when trying to center it

Tags: html, css

[image: ul green space]
As you can see on the image, this is a simple navbar:

```css
.upper-center {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<ul class="upper-center">
   <li><a>News</a></li>
   <li><a>Solutions</a></li>
   <li><a>Forum</a></li>
   <li><a>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Why is this **green square** taking some of the space from the whole UL element?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29307477/16688813

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<ul>` elements come with some inherent styling in the browser. If you set `padding: 0` on your `<ul>` in your css, you'll see that the green bar will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul {
display: block;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-block-start: 1em;
margin-block-end: 1em;
margin-inline-start: 0px;
margin-inline-end: 0px;
--> padding-inline-start: 40px;
}
```

those are default UL styles, you need to override **padding-inline-start** :)